# Object type cast in Java

Tags: java, class, object, casting

I'm struggling to understand the **C()** object created in this code.

I understand that when it is created on line 3, it is an object with the reference in the **A** class. I also understand that you can reference the same object on line 4 from a reference in the **B** class. However, I don't understand the casting of reference **o1** on line 4. Does this change the object or just how it is referenced?

Would really appreciate an explanation :) thanks

```
public class TestClass{
   public static void main(String args[ ] ){
      A o1 = new C( );
      B o2 = (B) o1;
      System.out.println(o1.m1( ) );
      System.out.println(o2.i );
   }
}
class A { int i = 10;  int m1( ) { return i; } }
class B extends A { int i = 20;  int m1() { return i; } }
class C extends B { int i = 30;  int m1() { return i; } }
```

Comment: Casting a reference in Java never changes the object, only the type of the reference. You're also making your example very confusing because you're *both* overriding a method *and* hiding a field.

Comment: Yes, this is a practice exam question, I wouldn't write code like this normally. I'm mainly confused as to why the output is 30 20

Comment: @Tommymitch because when you cast A to C, it calls `C::m1` which returns 30, and exact same answer for 20 - `i` is being shadowed, `m1` is being overriden.

Comment: Which is line 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
A o1 = new C( );
```

you assign an object of type `C` to a variable of type `A`.

`o1` can reference any object of class `A` or any sub-class of `A` (such as `B` and `C`). However, once you assign an object of class `C` to a variable of type `A`, you can only use that variable to execute methods declared in class `A` (or any super class of `A`).

If you want to execute methods of class `B`, you must tell the compiler that this variable actually references an object of class `B` (which is true, since that variable holds a reference to an object of class `C`, which is also of class `B`, since `C` extends `B`).

That's what the cast is for:

```
B o2 = (B) o1;
```

Now, using the variable `o2`, you can call methods declared in class `B`.

However, since all 3 classes declare a method of the same signature (`int m1( )`), the cast doesn't allow you to call a method you couldn't call via the `o1` variable. It does, however, give you access to the instance variable `i` of class `B` (by writing `o2.i`).

> Does this change the object or just how it is referenced?

It doesn't change the object. It just gives the compiler more detailed information about the actual type of the object referenced by that variable.

Comment: "you can only use that variable to execute methods" and access fields.

Comment: @AndyTurner yeah, by "only" I meant that you can't execute methods declared in classes `B` and `C` via `o1`.  The same applies to instance variables (though it's usually irrelevant, since instance variables are usually private).